# react hooks export functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a custom hook using ts that will be returning a function living inside it, the way I try to do it is:

```
export const useHook = () => {

  const function1 = () => {
 logic here
  };

const function2=()=>{

logic here
}

  return [function1,function2];
};
```

then i try to use it in a component like this:

```
import { useHook } from "./connector/useHook";

function App() {
  const {function1,function2} = useHook();

  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
      <button onClick={() => function1}>test</button>
      <button onClick={() => function2}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

however i get an error saying that

```
Property 'function1' does not exist on type '(() => void)[]'. 

const { function1, function2 } = useHook();
```

Comment: You are returning an array `return [function1,function2];`, but using the return value as an object `const {function1,function2} = useHook();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `{}` with `[]` since you are returning it as an array:

```js
const [function1, function2] = useHook();
```

or return an object from your hook:

```js
export const useHook = () => {

  const function1 = () => {
  // logic here
  };

  const function2 = () => {
  // logic here
  };

  return {function1, function2};
};
```

then you can use it as:

```js
cosnt {function1, function2} = useHook();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have returned your functions as the array `return [function1,function2];`. While you are using like `const {function1,function2} = useHook();`

So there are two approaches you can use

**Approach 1:**

Return your functions as an object from custom hook:

```
return { function1, function2 };
```

And use it like

```
const { function1, function2 } = useHook();
```

**Approach 2:**

Return your functions as an array from custom hook:

```
return [function1, function2];
```

And use it like

```
const [function1, function2] = useHook();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear answer :), some question comes to my head, is really any pathern for when to use one or the other?. thanks a lot again